# SSRS IIF statements expressions for conditional date formatting (BETWEEN)

Tags: date, reporting-services, conditional-statements, iif, ssrs-expression

I want to do a conditional format on date ranges. So if the date begin/end range (selected in the parameters `@Begin` and `@End`) is between 5 and 7 days, display "week", if **`between 28 days and 31 days`**, display `"Month"`, everything else, show `"X days"`, etc.

I have something like this, but syntactically doesn't compute. I'm struggling with this one so can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

**Example of what I have;**

```
=Iif(Parameters!DateBegin.Value = today() AND Parameters!DateEnd.Value = Today(), "Today", Iif(Parameters!DateBegin.Value = DateAdd("d",-1,Today()) AND Parameters!DateEnd.Value = Today(), "Yesterday", Iif(Parameters!DateBegin.Value AND Parameters!DateEnd.Value *difference is BETWEEN 5-7 days*, "Week", Iif(Parameters!DateBegin.Value AND Parameters!DateEnd.Value *difference is BETWEEN 28-31 days*, "Month", Everything else = *difference BETWEEN* Parameters!DateBegin.Value AND Parameters!DateEnd.Value & "days"
```

How do I go about achieving this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `DATEDIFF()` function.

For example(5-7 days):

```
Iif(
(DateDiff("d", Parameters!DateBegin.Value, Parameters!DateEnd.Value) > 4) AND (DateDiff("d", Parameters!DateBegin.Value, Parameters!DateEnd.Value) < 8), "Week", [etc]
```

Comment: Thanks that has worked. for the true parts of the statement. To get the 'ELSE' part out ive tried:         DateDiff("d", Parameters!DateBegin.Value, Parameters!DateEnd.Value) & "days"     but it looks as though its looking for a comparison operator at the end like =<>/

Comment: The only place it would look for a comparison operator is in the IIF statement.  The three parts of IIF are `Comparison Statement`, `Expression if True`, `Expression if false`.  The comparison statement has to resolve to a boolean true or false, so you might need to check your IIF nests.